# C# Generic DynamicMethod with no type parameters

Tags: c#, delegates, cil

For performance reasons, I am trying to write an IL delegate that can return a random `KeyValuePair` from a dictionary without having to use enumeration. To do this, I am directly reading from the dictionary's `_bucket` and `_entries` fields.

`Dictionary` is a generic collection, but I would like to avoid having to compile a delegate for each individual type and just return a boxed object instead. However, it appears that working with generics in this manner is a bit troublesome.

Here's where I'm currently at. Please note that the implementation is not complete:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{

    private delegate object RandomDelegate( IDictionary dict, Random random );
    private static RandomDelegate randomDel;

    static DictionaryExtensions()
    {
      randomDel = CompileRandomDel();
    }

    public static object RandomValue<TKey, TValue>( this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, Random rand )
    {
      var x = randomDel( dict, rand );
      return x;
    }

    private static RandomDelegate CompileRandomDel()
    {
      var bucketsField = typeof( Dictionary<,> ).GetField( "_buckets", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic );
      var entriesField = typeof( Dictionary<,> ).GetField( "_entries", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic );
      var randNext = typeof( Random ).GetMethod( "Next", Type.EmptyTypes );

      var method = new DynamicMethod(
        "RandomEntry",
        MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static,
        CallingConventions.Standard,
        typeof( object ),
        new[] { typeof( Dictionary<,> ), typeof( Random ) },
        typeof( DictionaryExtensions ),
        false );
      var il = method.GetILGenerator();
      il.DeclareLocal( typeof( int ) );         // Loc_0: Bucket

      il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldarg_1 );               // Load random
      il.Emit( OpCodes.Call, randNext );        // Get next random int

      //il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldarg_0 );             // Load dictionary
      //il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldfld, bucketsField ); // Load buckets
      //il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldlen );               // Load buckets length
      //il.Emit( OpCodes.Rem );                 // random % bucket count

      //il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldelem );              // Load bucket
      //il.Emit( OpCodes.Stloc_0 );             // Store bucket in loc_0

      //il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldarg_0 );             // Load dictionary
      //il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldfld, entriesField ); // Load dictionary entries
      //il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldloc_0 );             // Load bucket
      //il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldelem );              // Load element at bucket

      // Debug (just returning the random int for now)
      il.Emit( OpCodes.Conv_I4 );
      il.Emit( OpCodes.Box, typeof( int ) );
      il.Emit( OpCodes.Ret );

      return ( RandomDelegate ) method.CreateDelegate( typeof( RandomDelegate ) );
    }

}
```

My problem appears to be the lack of specific generic arguments. Running the method results in a `TypeInitialization: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B).`

If I change the DynamicMethod's parameters from `Dictionary<,>` to `IDictionary`, this works. However, this is dangerous, as not all `IDictionary` implementations are equal, and this delegate is meant only to be used on an actual `Dictionary<,>` type. In addition to this, it appears that the use of `IDictionary` might be screwing up the loading of fields, as it is throwing an `InvalidProgramException` when I try to load just the length of the `_entries` field and return it.

So, using a generic type without specifying parameters is a no-go. **Is there any other way to compile a safe delegate that will work with all generic type arguments?** Since the return value is just a boxed `object` I don't see the need to compile a delegate for each type it comes across, but if it is unavoidable I suppose I'll have no choice.

Comment: In short: No, not completely, because of code specializations that can happen with generic types. See here: http://joeduffyblog.com/2011/10/23/on-generics-and-some-of-the-associated-overheads/ (Essentially, the same generic type using different generic type parameters do not necessarily share code, which would make it impossible to use a single delegate to point at just one method entry, because there could be different code bases with respect to different generic type parameters) If generic type parameters are constrained to reference types, code sharing happens...

Comment: Why are you against creating a new dynamic method for every dictionary type it is used with? That's sufficiently generic and arguably the easiest to implement. The other option would be to create a dynamic assembly with the generic type/method, and the only performance difference there is the one between calling a dynamic method and a method in a dynamic assembly.